# Improve Performance of Grouped UITableView

Tags: uitableview

I am experiencing a long loading time for a grouped UITableView. I read through some other posts on the topic and was not able to find anything to improve the performance. I am looking for someone to point me in the right direction in re-engineering my code.

There are 8 sections and 32 cells. The cells belong to one of five different custom UITableView Cell  sub classes. The subclasses contain subviews and were put together using IB.

The TableView data is generated from a plist which also contains information on the cell type, the label and the View Controller Link to be pushed by the UINavigationController. A sample of the xml file is shown below. Could a complicated pList be part of the problem?

```
<dict>
        <key>Header</key>
        <string>Property Information</string>
        <key>Data</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>TableView</key>
                <string>informationTable</string>
                <key>Link</key>
                <string>ROIPropertyInfoUIViewController</string>
                <key>Entity</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>Image Name</key>
                <string>runtime</string>
                <key>Cell Type</key>
                <string>ROIUITableViewCellType3</string>
                <key>Label</key>
                <string>runtime</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

Another potential problem is a very long `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method which decides which class of UITableViewCell to load depending on what is written in the plist file. Could this be a contributing factor?

Here is the parsing code:

```
-(void)setPlistFilename:(NSString *)pList forTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

if (tableView==mainTableView) {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pList ofType:@"plist"];
        self.mainTableDataArray = [[NSArray alloc ] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSLog(@"count of mainTableArray is %d", mainTableDataArray.count);
}
```

[tableView setDataSource:self];
    [tableView setDelegate:self];

```
[tableView setSectionFooterHeight:0];
[tableView setSectionHeaderHeight:0];
```

}

Here is a portion of my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    NSMutableArray *tmpDataSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    if (tableView==self.mainTableView) {
        int section = [indexPath section];
        tmpDataSet = [[self.mainTableDataArray objectAtIndex:section] valueForKey:@"Data"];
    }


         //**Figure out the cell type
    NSString *cellTypeString = [[tmpDataSet objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] valueForKey:@"Cell Type"];
    NSLog(@"cell type string is %@", cellTypeString);
//***Create the different types of cells depending on what is listed in the pList***
    if ([cellTypeString isEqualToString:@"ROIUITableViewCellType1"]) {
        ROIUITableViewCellType1 *c = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellTypeString];

        if(!c)
        {
            c = [[ROIUITableViewCellType1 alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellTypeString];

        }
      //  mainTableViewHeight += [ROIUITableViewCellType1 retrunCellHeight];
        NSLog(@"mainTableViewHeight = %f", self.mainTableViewHeight);

        return [self setCellContentFromDataArray:tmpDataSet forCell:c forIndexNumer:[indexPath row]];
```

The Table only contains one image and does not load any data from a network.
I would like some advice on what I should spend time fixing.

Comment: Are you parsing the entire XML file into memory once and then using the parsed data, or are you parsing it every time you access the data?

Comment: I am parsing it once and storing into an NSArray Object.

Comment: Can we take a look at your code for parsing the file?